# I would, but vs I would have, but

Tags: grammar, tense

How should I use it?

> I would **have loved** to come, but I don't have time.
> I would **love** to come, but I don't have time.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is past tense. It would refer to something that has already happened and you didn't go it. So it should be "I would have loved to come, but I **didn't** have time"

The second sentence is present or future tense referring to something that is either currently happening or going to happen later. "I would love to come, but I don't have time." is the correct sentence here

If it is referring to something happening later you could also say "I would love to come, but I **won't** have time."